# Get the structure of the folders from the given path list as strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, path

Given a list of paths as:

```
'alpha/beta/gamma/delta alpha/beta/sigma beta/phi/pi/rho'
```

I want to Print it as:

```
-alpha
    -beta
        -gamma
            delta
        -sigma
-beta
    -phi
        -pi
            rho
```

Can you please help me out with this?
I was able to make a list of dictionaries of dictionaries. (I am kinda lost here)
There are simpler ways to do this where I can directly print the data but **I want to do it in a structure** such that I might be able to use this data somewhere else too.

```
paths = 'alpha/beta/gamma/delta alpha/beta/sigma b/f/g/h r/g/t/y q/w/er/rat'
folder_list = []

def get_children(ippath, e_dict):
    remaining_path = '/'.join(ippath.split('/')[1:])
    try:
        splitted_path = ippath.split('/')[0]
        if splitted_path:
            e_dict[splitted_path] = {}
            e_dict[splitted_path].update(get_children(remaining_path, e_dict[ippath.split('/')[0]]))
            return e_dict
        else:
            return e_dict
    except:
        return remaining_path

for path in paths.split(' '):
    end_dict = dict()
    output = get_children(path, end_dict)
    if output:
        folder_list.append(output)
        # final_list.update(output)
    else:
        continue

print(folder_list)
```

It gives me a list of nested dictionaries but still not what I want.

Thank you, I really appreciate the help

Comment: each of the keys is a directory, for each dict just print the keys one after the another and you get the path you want

Comment: But I get a new dictionary for every path that I have, in this case, I get the 2 different paths for first 2 folders.
I am not quite sure how to merge those 2 dictionaries because that would require a list.
Something like this..
[{'alpha': {'beta': {'gamma': {'delta': {}}}}}, {'alpha': {'beta': {'sigma': {}}}}, {'beta': {'phi': {'pi': {'rho': {}}}}}]

Comment: oh, ok. I didn't understand your initial question! Sorry.

Comment: Maybe I did not write it clearly, please suggest changes if something is confusing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution:

- First, build a set of all distinct full paths, including the intermediate paths.
- Sort the paths. This puts them in [depth-first order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), guaranteeing that a parent directory will always appear before its children.
- Iterate through the paths, maintaining a stack:

  - Pop from the stack until you find the parent of the current path.
  - Print just the difference between the current path and its parent. The indentation level is determined by the length of the stack.
  - Push the current path to the stack.

To get the `-` symbols in the right place, we can keep track of which paths are leaf nodes in the tree. Here's the code:

```py
def dir_tree(s):
    paths = set()
    for path in s.split():
        parts = path.split('/')
        is_leaf = True
        while parts:
            path = '/'.join(parts) + '/'
            paths.add( (path, is_leaf) )
            parts.pop()
            is_leaf = False

    stack = ['']
    for path, is_leaf in sorted(paths):
        while not path.startswith(stack[-1]):
            stack.pop()
        suffix = path[len(stack[-1]):-1]
        tabs = len(stack) - 1
        print('\t'*tabs + ('' if is_leaf else '-') + suffix)
        stack.append(path)
```

Output:

```
-alpha
    -beta
        -gamma
            delta
        sigma
-beta
    -phi
        -pi
            rho
```

Comment: Your answer is really way better than the one I found out! But I want to export the structure to some other function and I think I need all that data in a single variable. 
But given the context I like the way you solved it..
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you fine with using another library? if so, dpath will work great for this.
It allows you to create dicts based on strings

https://pypi.org/project/dpath/

Comment: They seem to do the trick but I can not use any other libraries.
Still thank you, I will look into their structure and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work.. :)
[Ron Serruya's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2126254/ron-serruya) suggested library helped me rethink my structure.

```
import json
paths = 'alpha/beta/gamma/delta alpha/beta/sigma beta/phi/pi/rho'
folder_list = {}

def get_children(ippath, e_dict):
    remaining_path = '/'.join(ippath.split('/')[1:])
    try:
        splitted_path = ippath.split('/')[0]
        if splitted_path:
            e_dict[splitted_path] = {}
            e_dict[splitted_path].update(get_children(remaining_path, e_dict[ippath.split('/')[0]]))
            return e_dict
        else:
            return e_dict
    except:
        return remaining_path

def merge_dictionaries(new_dictionary, main_dictionary):
    key = list(new_dictionary.keys())[0]
    if list(new_dictionary[key].keys())[0] in list(main_dictionary[key].keys()):
        merge_dictionaries(new_dictionary[key], main_dictionary[key])
    else:
        main_dictionary[key][list(new_dictionary[key].keys())[0]] = new_dictionary[key][list(new_dictionary[key].keys())[0]]

def main():
    for path in paths.split(' '):
        end_dict = dict()
        output = get_children(path, end_dict)
        if output:
            if list(output.keys())[0] not in list(folder_list.keys()):
                folder_list.update(output)
            else:
                merge_dictionaries(output, folder_list)
        else:
            continue
    print(str(json.dumps(folder_list, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=('', ''))).replace('{', '').replace('}', ''))

main()
```

Gives Output:

```
    "alpha"
        "beta"
            "gamma"
                "delta"

            "sigma"


    "beta"
        "phi"
            "pi"
                "rho"
```

Sorry for really bad structure of the code, I am up for suggestion to improve this structurally.